# How to center the content of (centered) pure css columns

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

The snippet presents a series of columns containing a single letter. I'd like to have the center of the glyph in the center of each, but as you can see, they not quite centered -- appearing just off to the right.  (I suspect by half the glyph width, but I'm not sure).

I've tried `justify-content: center`, `margin: auto` to no avail.  Inspecting the pure, I don't see anything that should prevent what I'm aiming for.  Can you help me fix it?

```css
.centered-cols {
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 1.9em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="pure-g centered-cols">
  <div id="q" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>A</p></div>
  <div id="w" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>B</p></div>
  <div id="e" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>C</p></div>
  <div id="r" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>D</p></div>
  <div id="t" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>E</p></div>
  <div id="y" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>F</p></div>
  <div id="u" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>G</p></div>
  <div id="i" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>H</p></div>
  <div id="o" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>I</p></div>
  <div id="p" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>J</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `letter-spacing: 0` in your `.key` css class:

```css
.key {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 1.9em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="pure-g centered-cols">
  <div id="q" class="pure-u-1-10 key">
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div id="w" class="pure-u-1-10 key">
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div id="e" class="pure-u-1-10 key">
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div id="r" class="pure-u-1-10 key">
    <p>D</p>
  </div>
  <div id="t" class="pure-u-1-10 key">
    <p>E</p>
  </div>
  <div id="y" class="pure-u-1-10 key">
    <p>F</p>
  </div>
  <div id="u" class="pure-u-1-10 key">
    <p>G</p>
  </div>
  <div id="i" class="pure-u-1-10 key">
    <p>H</p>
  </div>
  <div id="o" class="pure-u-1-10 key">
    <p>I</p>
  </div>
  <div id="p" class="pure-u-1-10 key">
    <p>J</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure is creating this problem by setting a `letter-spacing: -.31em` in the `pure-g` CSS class.

Just set `letter-spacing: normal !important;` to overwrite it:

```css
.centered-cols {
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: normal !important;
}

.key {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 2.9em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="pure-g centered-cols">
  <div id="q" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>A</p></div>
  <div id="w" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>B</p></div>
  <div id="e" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>C</p></div>
  <div id="r" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>D</p></div>
  <div id="t" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>E</p></div>
  <div id="y" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>F</p></div>
  <div id="u" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>G</p></div>
  <div id="i" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>H</p></div>
  <div id="o" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>I</p></div>
  <div id="p" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>J</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove     `letter-spacing: -.31em;` in pure-g class

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS grid if you want equal width item and you can easily center them:

```css
.centered-cols {
  display:grid;
  width:max-content;
  margin:auto;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
}

.key {
  text-align:center;
  padding:0 .8em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="centered-cols">
  <div id="q" class="key"><p>A</p></div>
  <div id="w" class="key"><p>B</p></div>
  <div id="e" class="key"><p>C</p></div>
  <div id="r" class="key"><p>D</p></div>
  <div id="t" class="key"><p>E</p></div>
  <div id="y" class="key"><p>F</p></div>
  <div id="u" class="key"><p>G</p></div>
  <div id="i" class="key"><p>H</p></div>
  <div id="o" class="key"><p>I</p></div>
  <div id="p" class="key"><p>J</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we are already in the realms of flexbox, something like this could also work, without the need for !important

```css
.centered-cols {
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  min-width: 1.9em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="pure-g centered-cols">
  <div id="q" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>A</p></div>
  <div id="w" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>B</p></div>
  <div id="e" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>C</p></div>
  <div id="r" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>D</p></div>
  <div id="t" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>E</p></div>
  <div id="y" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>F</p></div>
  <div id="u" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>G</p></div>
  <div id="i" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>H</p></div>
  <div id="o" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>I</p></div>
  <div id="p" class="pure-u-1-10 key"><p>J</p></div>
</div>
```